# Compare Array key value with the given name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi i am working on some array operations with loop.

I want to compare array key value with the given name.

But i am unable to get exact output.

**This is my array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] =>  
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => 3M
            [value] => 76
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Test
            [value] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => Test1
            [value] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => Test2
            [value] => 6
        )
)
```

**This is my varriable** which i need to compare : `$test_name = "Test2";`

**Below Code which  i have tried :**

```
 $details // getting array in this varriable
if($details['label'] == $test_name)
{
    return $test_name;
}
else
{
    return "NotFound";
}
```

But every time its returns NotFound.

Not getting what exactly issue.

Comment: Give your loop code so can iterate and give a particular answer.

Comment: @Manthan Dave updated the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @Manthan Dave try with array_column and in_array() like below:

```
<?php
if(in_array($test_name, array_column($details, "label"))){
    return $test_name;
}
else
{
    return "NotFound";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$details` is a multidimensional array, but you are trying to access it like a simple array.
You need too loop through it:

```
foreach ($details as $item) {
    if($item['label'] == $test_name)
    {
        return $test_name;
    }
    else
    {
        return "NotFound";
    }
}
```

I hope your array can never contain a label `NotFound`... :)

Answer (score 2):

You have array inside array try with below,

```
if($details[4]['label'] == $test_name)
{
    return $test_name;
}
else
{
    return "NotFound";
}
```

Although foreach loop should work but if not try as,

```
for($i=0; $i<count($details); $i++){

    if($details[$i]['label'] == $test_name)
    {
        return $test_name;
    }
    else
    {
        return "NotFound";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `in_array` and `array_column` without use of `foreach` loop as

```
if (in_array($test_name,array_column($details, 'label')))
{
    return $test_name;
}
else
{
    return "NotFound";
}
```

Comment: same logic :D now what to do ?

Comment: want to do dynamically

Comment: @Saty but your answer is not correct, it will output nothing

Comment: Ahh my bad!! chnage column name to `label`@ManthanDave and check!!

Comment: @Saty now your answer is fine (y)

Comment: @BunkerBoy yes same logic!! we think like same!! :D enjoy!

Comment: @Saty yes but as you have more repo than me so the user are thinking that i copied your answer but that's not the right

Comment: @ManthanDave dynamically what you do please explain!!

Comment: @BunkerBoy It's depend upon people thinking. Well times matter for posting answer.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to check only the if condition like below because else meet at first time it will return the "notfound" then it will not execute.

```
$result = 'NotFound';
foreach ($details as $item) {
    if($item['label'] == $test_name)
    {
        $result = $test_name;
    }
}
return $result;
```

or

```
$result = 'NotFound';
if (in_array($test_name,array_column($details, 'label')))
{
    $result = $test_name;
}
return $result;
```

Comment: your answer is not correct, it will output nothing for the 1 st case

Comment: why? can you explain?

Comment: now fine you have  edited the column name 'firstname' to 'label'

Answer (score 2):

Traverse your array like this,

```
array_walk($array, function($v) use($test_name){echo $v['label'] == $test_name ? $test_name : "NotFound";});
```

Comment: thumbs up for array walk